# How Can I Remove the 1st Matching Element From a List Without a Cut

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to delete the first matching item from a list without using backtracking, basically, the first occurrence of the element and then stop the backtracking and provide no more solutions.

I have this which works great:

```
% delete an item from a list, only one, no back tracking, using cut
delete_one( X, [X|Tail], Tail ) :- !.
delete_one( X, [Y|Tail], [Y|Tail1] ) :- delete_one(X,Tail,Tail1).
```

This works well. My problem is achieving the same goal without the use of cut, but using the `not` predicate instead. This is what I have tried:

```
% the same as above without using cut
delete_one_no_cut(X,[X|Tail],Tail).
delete_one_no_cut(X,[Y|Tail],[Y,Tail1]) :-
  not(X==Y),
  delete_one_no_cut(X,Tail,Tail1).
```

It doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Note the  `, ` in the third parameter of the second clase. It should be  `[Y|Tail1] `. Also instead of  `not/1 ` use  `\+ /1` or directly  `X\=Y ` (or  `dif/2 `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of operations. Most recursive problems have 1 or 2 terminating special cases and one general recursive case. You have two terminating special cases:

- Once you find an empty list, you're done.
- Once you find a matching term at the head of the list, you're done.

And one general recursive case:

- The head of the list doesn't match the supplied value.

The trick is the order of evaluation. Try something like this:

```
delete_first( _ , []    , []     ) .
delete_first( X , [H|T] , [H|T1] ) :- X \= H , delete_first(X, T, T1 ) .
delete_first( X , [X|T] , T      ) .
```

Comment: Why would you use this version over mine?

Comment: Mine takes into account the empty list. Yours fails if either the source list is empty, or a matching item is not found. Also, your solution uses `dif/2`, which is not standard ISO prolog. The request was for using `not`/1, and `A \= B`  is semantically the same as `not( A = B )`, whilst `dif/2` is not.

Comment: ok, I think failing if not found makes sense, yours fails for `delete_first(X,[1,2],Y),X=2.` which could be a problem depending on use. `not/1` and `\=` implementation has a cut I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
x_list_list2(X,[X|T],T).
x_list_list2(X,[H|T],[H|New]):-
    dif(X,H),
    x_list_list2(X,T,New).
```